# dynamic mail subject not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates, html

I am trying to set the dynamic mail subject, but it is not working.

I tried below ways.

1    `<!--@subject Product Question : @--> {{ var sku }}<!-- from
    StoreName @-->`

2. `<!--@subject Product Question : {{ var sku }} from StoreName @-->`
3. `<!--@subject Product Question : @sku from StoreName @-->`

But not working above ways.

```
<!--@subject {{var sku|raw }}@ " from StoreName"-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"skin url=\"images/logo_email.gif\" _area='frontend'":"Email Logo Image"}
@-->
<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px;font-weight:normal;line-height:22px;margin:0 0 11px 0;">{{trans "Hello"}}, {{trans "Admin"}}</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; color:#504F50">
                                        <table style="width: 100%;">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                     {{var message}}
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="font-size:12px;border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA; color:#504F50">
                                         <p style="font-size:12px;margin:0;">
                                            <strong>{{trans "Thank you"}}</strong>
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
 {{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Any help on this will appreciate?

Comment: Have you got value of sku in body structure?

Comment: @Rakesh No I am trying..

Comment: @Rakesh Any help?

Comment: please show your template file where you have define above code.

Comment: @Rakesh see I have Updated my thread

Comment: you can just keep line <!--@subject {{var sku}} from StoreName @--> at top instead of your line

Comment: ok sure i will post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to kee below line in your template file to get dynamic value of sku in email template.

Just keep {{var sku}} in single state line same as below,

```
 <!--@subject {{var sku}} from StoreName @-->
```

Clear cache and check.

Comment: Hope you have like answer. Welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I am Implementing a custom module and sending email by code mentioned in this Link

https://webkul.com/blog/magento-2-send-transactional-email-programmatically-in-your-custom-module/

To set Dynamic Subject I have replaced "@subject Subject Of your email " by "

`@subject {{var subject|raw }}@ " in my html file which I put under NameSpace\Modulename\view\frontend\email\filename.html`

Value to subject variable is passed from Helper file which is mentioned in the above link

Comment: I tried `@subject {{var sku|raw }}@ " from YumWarehouse "`  but it is showing on body.